# Lua Script to get date and time from apache tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, lua

How to write script to retrieve the current date and time from Apache Tomcat server in Lua.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/) so that you can connect to your server. It does not have to be a Tomcat server. Try running this code:

```
local http = require "socket.http" -- import the socket.http module
local body, httpcode, headers = http.request("http://www.google.com")
local date = headers.date -- LuaSocket makes all header names lowercase
print(date) --> "Mon, 18 Feb 2013 09:03:13 GMT" in my case
```